# HTML Table EDIT Using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to edit the data in html table with code example here 
[edit table data](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/demos/user_manager.html)
but if I add one more column to the table I need to write code in JS to get the label and data in JS popup(lables names & table row class names are static), instead of that can I get the popup dynamically with table all heading as label names and row data in the corresponding text box for any number of columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a CodePen or JSFiddle to better demonstrate the problem you're having?

Comment: The Problem is just i want to add one more column to table and edit that column data also but I don't want do changes in JS. new column should come dynamically in the popup box for edit